# Ajax: The content type text\/html of the response message does not match the content type of the binding (application\/soap+xml; charset=utf-8)

Tags: html, xml, ajax, wcf, iis

I've been reading for hours posts related with "The content type text/html of the response message does not match the content type of the binding (application/soap+xml; charset=utf-8)" issue
But non of them seem to solve my problem.

Let me explain:

I have an ajax call to a WCF method which returns a json object.

[image: Ajax Call]

ok now my wcf service is located in the same app (don't ask me why):

[image: WCF]

this is the unique web.config that the app has.

```
<services>
    <service behaviorConfiguration="defaultBehavior" name="HSMobileApp.Services.HSMobile">

        <endpoint address="pox" behaviorConfiguration="poxBehavior" binding="webHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="webBinding" contract="HSMobileApp.Services.IHSMobile" />

    <host>
        <baseAddresses>
            <add baseAddress="/Services/HSMobile" />
        </baseAddresses>
    </host>
    </service>
</services>

<bindings>
  <webHttpBinding>
    <binding name="webBinding" />
  </webHttpBinding>
</bindings>

<behaviors>
  <endpointBehaviors>
    <behavior name="poxBehavior">
      <webHttp defaultOutgoingResponseFormat="Xml" />
    </behavior>
    <behavior name="jsonBehavior">
        <webHttp defaultOutgoingResponseFormat="Json" />
    </behavior>
  </endpointBehaviors>

  <serviceBehaviors>
    <behavior name="defaultBehavior">
      <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" />
      <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true" />
    </behavior>
  </serviceBehaviors>
</behaviors>
```

So, my ajax calls the svc that I'm hosting in the same application, In the Visual Studio 2010 environment works fine, but when I try to debug it on the IIS this is what I got after reaching the WCF method.

> "Associate":0,"MenuOptions":"The content type text/html of the response message does not match the content type of the binding (application/soap+xml; charset=utf-8). If using a custom encoder, be sure that the IsContentTypeSupported method is implemented properly. The first 1024 bytes of the response were:...

I know this must be somekind of binding o IIS situation but I don't know where to look at, because my server web.config is the same that the client web.config

I'm working in a Windows 7 Enterprise, IIS 7.5, VS2010 and jquery 1.6.2

Please help me!!

Comment: In your web.config you never actually use the 'jsonBehaviour' for anything, so the 'pox' endpoint always assumes XML. Your client machine.config might be doing something with the "automaticFormatSelectionEnabled" setting and/or default endpoint which allow it to change the output type depending on the request details.

Comment: Sorry, jsonBehaviour was a test that I left. My mstk

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can delete the "jsonBehaviour" (as it's not used) and try putting this inside your "poxBehaviour":

```
<webHttp automaticFormatSelectionEnabled ="true" />
```

You should also be able to simplify your service and just use the following:

```
<endpoint address="pox" behaviorConfiguration="poxBehavior" kind="webHttpEndpoint" contract="HSMobileApp.Services.IHSMobile" />
```

In your AJAX request you can set the accept header or content-type to explicitly tell the server you want a JSON result otherwise it will use to the default format, [see here for more details on the "automaticFormatSelectionEnabled" setting](http://aspdotnetcodebook.blogspot.co.uk/2011/01/how-to-return-multiple-response-from.html).

Note that this assumes your WCF attributes are set appropriately in your server code (which they probably are otherwise it would have never worked).

Comment: Thanks for your response. I forgot to install the ServiceModel on the IIS and RESTART THE PC!!! Man!... hehehe. Thanks

Comment: Easily done! First time I tried to host an MVC4 app it took me ages to figure out what I had missed...